# can't get location - entering while loop

Tags: geolocation, location

i am still new in android studio and trying to create an app that will just log my location, when i run it i get no errors but it doesn't get the location logged, instead the app is kind of trapped in a while loop from the start, i am using my phone not the emulator (Sony Xperia XA Ultra with Nougat 7.0) and my android studio version is 2.2.1, here is the code:

```
package com.mohamed.locationdemo;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // declarations
    LocationManager locationManager; LocationListener locationListener;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // initiations
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewID);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            // when the user change his location
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.i("Location is: ", location.toString()); // var location here represents the cords of the phone location
                textView.setText(location.toString());
            }

            @Override
            // called when the location service is either enabled or disabled
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
                textView.setText(s); Log.i("on status changed", "");
            }

            @Override
            // only when the location service enabled
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
                textView.setText(s); Log.i("on provider enabled", "");
            }

            @Override
            // only when the location service is disabled
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                textView.setText(s); Log.i("on provider disabled", "");
            }
        };


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

        }
        else
        {
            // if we have permission then we will get the location directly
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 10, locationListener);
            Log.i("in the else condition", "");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        // now we will check if the user answered with yes, then we will get the phone location using LocationManager class
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {Log.i("on request permission", "");
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 10, locationListener); Log.i("getting loca in methode", "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the XML Manifest: 
[XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pvQU.png)
and the Log: 
[LOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCZpe.png)

Comment: Please write a minimum viable example to reproduce your problem.  Also, please clarify what you have tried so far to fix this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to solve it by modifying in the file [build.gradle (module app)] the google play services version from

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4
```

to be

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2
```

not sure if this can be done in a production app but for the sake of learning it worked for me, i got my phone and the emulator working just fine...